# Label on click navigation using JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to be able to click on a label to navigate to new page, i don't want to use a link  to do it, because it must have a feel of a button!

html :

```
<label id="+"pagego"+" style="+"text-align:center;"+"font-size:x-large;"+">"+ data[i].ProcessName +"</label>
```

i know it looks weird, but i am using that label in a for loop in jquery to populate the label with data i get from a web-service, now how can i get this label to be clicked on, i have seen people talking about *window.location.href* and even a few people going on about *$(#pagego).click(function(){* i am very new in this and i would like to know how am i going to get this label to navigate me to a new page! thanks!

using : cordova1.9/html5/javascript/jquery

Comment: _"...because it must have a feel of a button"_ - So why don't you use a button? Note that if you are creating a series of labels in a loop with that line of code in the loop then you are giving them all the same id attribute which is invalid html.

Comment: Please can you post all the relevant code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: use a link and style it any way you want so it "feels like a button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label id="+"pagego"+" style="+"text-align:center;"+"font-size:x-large;"+">"+ data[i].ProcessName +"</label>
```

note that you could not have same ID for more than one item in a DOM. so we have to change the code like

```
<label id="+"pagego"+i+" style="+"text-align:center;"+"font-size:x-large;"+" onclick='redirectme()'>"+ data[i].ProcessName +"</label>

<script>
function redirectme()
{
location.href='example.html'
}
</script>
```

Comment: you understood exactly what i needed thanks for quick reply this worked just as i wanted to, only one change is i made is i used window.location.href! i have one problem though, sometimes the labels dont want to be clicked i neeed to reload page before they work? any ideaswhy this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, first moving your style into a css block. once done you can do something like

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #pagego {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:x-large;
    }
</style>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pagego').value = data[i].ProcessName;

        $('#pagego').onclick(function(){
            // to submit the form:
            $('#formID').submit();

            // to navigate:
            document.location.href = "new page address";
        });
    }
</script>
```

and your html:

```
<input id="pagego"><input>
```